# Prove that $(A × B) ∩ (C × D) ⊇ (A ∩ C) × (B ∩ D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me with this please? I did find different solutions through the Internet, but they do not say the same:

> Prove or show counterexample: $$(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) \supseteq (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$$

Comment: Please, learn to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I would start with: Let $(x,y) \in (A\cap C) \times (B \cap D) $ and try to use definitions.

Comment: For future questions, please try to include as much of your own work as possible. As it is, this question is very low effort.

Comment: I am sorry. I feel sad about -3 research effort. Next time I will include all the usefull stuff I will find or think about. I did find some possible answers for this problem too, but was not so sure, so I excluded it. You know, I am just a newbie :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in (A\cap C) \times (B\cap D)$.

$\Rightarrow x\in (A\cap C)$ and $y\in (B\cap D)$
$\Rightarrow x\in A$ and $x\in C$, $y\in B$ and $y\in D$
$\Rightarrow (x,y) \in A\times B$ and $(x,y) \in C\times D$
$\Rightarrow (x,y) \in (A\times B) \cap (C\times D)$

You just use definitions of intersection and what you know about sets like $I_1 \times I_2 \times ...$

Answer (score 0):

If $(x,y) \in (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$ then $x \in A \cap C$ and $y \in B \cap D$. Thus in particular $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, so $(x,y) \in A \times B$, and similarly $(x,y) \in C \times D$, so $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cap (C \times D)$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Take some $x \in (A\cap C) \times (B\cap D)$. Then $x = (x_1, x_2)$ for some $x_1 \in A \cap C$ and $x_2 \in B \cap D$. However, this means that $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$, so $x = (x_1, x_2) \in A \times B$. Try to do the same thing to show it is also in $C\times D$, and you will get your inclusion.